# How to import multiple different collections using mongo import in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to import multiple json files into different collections in my mongo database but only the last imported collection is kept.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mongo-seed
  mongo-seed:
    build: ./mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
  mongo_db:
    image: "mongo:4.4.3"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE="mongo_db"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

And the mongo-seed Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

COPY ./data/users.json /users.json
CMD mongoimport --drop --host mongo_db --db aada_backend --collection users --type json --file /users.json --jsonArray

COPY ./data/headphones.json /headphones.json
CMD mongoimport --drop --host mongo_db --db aada_backend --collection headphones --type json --file /headphones.json --jsonArray

COPY ./data/earbuds.json earbuds.json
CMD mongoimport --drop --host mongo_db --db aada_backend --collection earbuds --type json --file /earbuds.json --jsonArray
```

I couldn't find anything online about how to import multiple collections into one database, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you [cannot have more than one CMD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) in the Dockerfile. When you do, only the last one will be executed, this is by design. What you can do within you seed container -

- copy the jsons to the seed container
- copy a shell script containing mongoimport commands to the seed container
- make CMD execute this script.

For example:

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /jsondata

COPY ./jsondata/ .
COPY ./seed.sh .

RUN chmod +x seed.sh

CMD ["sh", "-c", "/jsondata/seed.sh"]
```

then in the docker-compose.yaml you can have it configured this way:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo-seed:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it work :). Didn't know you were restricted to only one CMD command per dockerfile

Comment: Correct, I've updated the answer to have a reference to the official doc about that.

Comment: This works like a charm! However, for me the command

`CMD ["sh", "-c", "/jsondata/seed.sh"]`

didn't work, I had to change it to:

`CMD ["/jsondata/seed.sh"]`