# How can one import data into a mongodb service in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have been having problems using mongodb as a service in docker-compose. I managed to insert data into its container (csv, txt and json files, for instance) at `data/db/` through a volume folder, but I still can`t use it as a collection. I believe I should use the function` mongoimport`, but it fails to connect to the host. All seems to be fine but the host. I have tried a lot of other addresses as hosts, but none have worked.

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

    mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.6
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
        volumes:
            - ./mongodbvol:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27107:27107"
        command:
            mongoimport --host http://0.0.0.0:27017 -c col1 --type csv --file /data/db/tt.csv --headerline
        
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        container_name: mongo-express
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=example
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=necode
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=passwd
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        depends_on:
            - mongodb

    rshiny:
        image: guigo13/app
        container_name: rshiny
        restart: on-failure
        command: R -e "shiny::runApp('R/app.R', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"
        environment:
            - DB_URI=mongodb
            - DB_USERNAME=root
            - DB_PASSWORD=example
            - DB_NAME=appdb
            - DB_HOST=mongodb
            - DB_PORT=27017
        ports:
            - "3838:3838"
            - "3839:3838"
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
```

and here is the error from the logs

```
mongodb          | 2021-10-29T02:51:09.170+0000 [########################] test.col1    11B/11B (100.0%)
mongodb          | 2021-10-29T02:51:09.685+0000 [########################] test.col1    11B/11B (100.0%)
mongodb          | 2021-10-29T02:51:09.685+0000 Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
mongodb          | 2021-10-29T02:51:09.685+0000 imported 0 documents
```

Could someone, please, get me an alternative?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are overriding the default CMD for the mongo image (which is running the db service -  CMD ["mongod"]). This makes it impossible for the container to connect to itself). Also I think the default port for mongo is 27017, and not 27107.

I've seen people using a separate container to seed the data to the database, where all it does - it runs the mongoimport to populate the data and then dies. You could try thi approach. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760892/how-to-import-multiple-different-collections-using-mongo-import-in-docker/69762551#69762551), this may give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import it just once, I would advice to create an own image:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:versiontag

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME root
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD example
ENV MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE mydb

COPY mongodb.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN mongod --fork --logpath=/tmp/mongodb.log && sleep 20 && \
  mongoimport -c=users -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/users.json && \
  mongoimport -c=tasks -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/tasks.json && \
  mongoimport -c=configs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/configs.json && \
  mongoimport -c=agentGroupConfigs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/agentGroupConfigs.json && \
  mongoimport -c=col1 --type=csv --file=/data/db/tt.csv --headerline
```

It is firing up the mongo while creating the container and fills it then.

in the mongodb.js you can script additional `mongosh` commands, like adding users, dbs or insert data and so on.

**Edit:** Small brainbug. Should do the `RUN` stuff in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` to be sure it just did once. Entrypoint-scripts are not executed if db-folder exists. Therefore:

```
COPY mongodb.js prefill.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

prefill.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod --fork --logpath=/tmp/mongodb.log 
sleep 20
mongoimport -c=users -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/users.json
mongoimport -c=tasks -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/tasks.json
mongoimport -c=configs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/configs.json
mongoimport -c=agentGroupConfigs -d=acrc --mode=upsert --file=/opt/acrc/config/agentGroupConfigs.json
mongoimport -c=col1 --type=csv --file=/data/db/tt.csv --headerline
```